# Change Tag Permalink Structure

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

In Tags Page I want the default permalink be `/tag/key-word` on a tag click.

I want change

```
https://example.com/tag/key-word
```

to

```
https://example.com/?s=key+word
```

Comment: Hi Med, How about sharing some of the ways you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a filter for term_link action and format url in your function. (I'm assuming you want the search url for tag title.)

```
add_filter('term_link', 'term_link_filter', 10, 3);
function term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if ($taxonomy == 'post_tag') {
        return get_search_link( $term->name ) ;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Hope this helps.